# How to fix PlotlyRequestError?

Tags: python, plotly

I get an 'PlotlyRequestError: No message' when I execute the code.

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

Filedata = pd.read_csv('C:\\Documents\\Book4.csv')
data = [go.Scatter(x=Filedata.ix[:,0],y=Filedata.ix[:,1])]
layout = go.Layout(
title='Analysis 2016',
xaxis=dict(title='Startdate'),
yaxis=dict(title='Conductivity'))

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: did the below answer fix your problem? if yes, request you to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 15):

This is because you are trying to plot online which requires credentials based authentication. To plot offline, use plotly.offline's plot class to accomplish this without authentication.

```
from  plotly.offline import plot
```

and then use this plot to plot your figure.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and I solved the problem by importing plotly like this:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
# these two lines allow your code to show up in a notebook
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode()
```

And then calling iplot like this:

```
plotly.offline.iplot(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved the problem by importing plotly and cufflinks like this:

```py
from plotly.offline import iplot
import cufflinks as cf
```

and then apply

```py
cf.go_offline()
```

Answer (score 0):

!pip install plotly
!pip install cufflinks
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()

df.iplot()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?