# I got: chart_studio.exceptions.PlotlyRequestError: Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: python, plotly, ohlc

I am working locally(in my pc) just testing and learning PLOTLY  3.7.5.
with anaconda env active.
The code example is given by plotly

Code:

```
import plotly.plotly as py  # Here all begins (Look)
# import chart_studio.plotly as py  # inted of the line bellow (optional to  try)
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')
    trace = go.Ohlc(x=df['Date'],
                    open=df['AAPL.Open'],
                    high=df['AAPL.High'],
                    low=df['AAPL.Low'],
                    close=df['AAPL.Close'])
    data = [trace]
    py.iplot(data, filename='simple_ohlc')
```

note  (Look): I got the warning error:

> *'please install the chart-studio package and use the chart_studio.plotly module instead.'*

Comment: this [issue](https://community.plot.ly/t/solved-update-to-plotly-4-0-0-broke-application/26526) seems related

Comment: I think the error message is very clear.

Answer (score 17):

You need plotly's offline mode to obviate authentication - following https://stackoverflow.com/a/44694854/1021819, rather do:

```
from plotly.offline import iplot
```

Comment: I still get the error (working inside Jupyter notebooks)

Answer (score 4):

use below line of code before hitting iplot

```
cf.go_offline() #will make cufflinks offline
cf.set_config_file(offline=False, world_readable=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from  plotly.offline import plot
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot,iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected='true')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4),columns='A B C D'.split())
df.head()
df.iplot(kind='box')
```

Answer (score 0):

Basics for starting Plotly and Cufflinks section:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  
%matplotlib inline  
from plotly import __version__ 
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import cufflinks as cf
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()
```

Answer (score -4):

Call these two below library automatically problem will be solved

`import chart_studio.plotly as py`

Comment: 'chart_studio.plotly' is still "one" library you're importing... "as py" doesn't count as second library because its only a renaming... what is missing...